# AngularJS: How to refer to the $invalid variable of a form from the controller?

Tags: html, angularjs, forms, controller

I am developing a web application using AngularJS. I have a problem: my application uses predefined components (created by other developers) as input fields of various forms. These fields have their own custom validation methods for each component and I don't know anything about them. However, I must have **in my controller** the (boolean) information that indicates whether the form is valid or not.
The solution I found is this:

**HTML:**

```
<form name="myForm"></form>
<form name="myForm">

        <custom-component-1
                                custom-property1="someString"
                                custom-property2="someString"                                    
        ></custom-component-1>

         <custom-component-2
                                custom-property1="someString"
                                custom-property2="someString"                                    
        ></custom-component-2>
    </div>
</form>
```

Now, if I use directly in my template the following string: `{{myForm.$invalid}}`  it behaves correctly, printing on the screen the boolean true (if there is something not valid) or the boolean false (if everything goes well). My problem is that **I don't know how to map this variable in the controller at run-time**. Surely there is a way, but unfortunately I know very little about AngularJS! For example, if in my controller I use this variable, like this:

```
console.log("My variable: ", myForm.$invalid)
```

The output value is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

### html

```
<form name="varObj.myForm" ng-submit="formSubmitCall();">

        <custom-component-1
                                custom-property1="someString"
                                custom-property2="someString"                                    
        ></custom-component-1>

         <custom-component-2
                                custom-property1="someString"
                                custom-property2="someString"                                    
        ></custom-component-2>
    </div>
</form>
```

### js

In controller initialize varObj as:

```
    $scope.varObj = {};

    $scope.formSubmitCall = function(){
        console.log("My variable: ", $scope.varObj.myForm.$invalid);
    }
```